# Quick PMSM FOC PI controler design

Tags: motor-controller, pid-controller, matlab, simulink, pmsm

For a Simulink Model I am looking for a quick and easy way to estimate PI-controller parameters for a speed control loop and Id and Iq controler of a PMSM using FOC.
I don't have a real motor just the datasheet of [RPX22-042V24](https://www.electrocraft.com/files/downloads/Datasheets/bldc/RPX22-DataSheet-US.pdf)

Is there any easy way to estimate controler parameters?

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is facing the same problem: I had a good experience with "A Model-based PI Controller Tuning and Design for Field
Oriented Current Control of Permanent Magnet Synchronous
Motor" from Kenneth C. Odo et.al

At least for the current controller. It's not perfect but it works and it's no big effort.

https://iosrjournals.org/iosr-jeee/Papers/Vol14%20Issue%204/Series-2/E1404023541.pdf